# Lost owner privileges on Android 10 after flashing boot image

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, multi-user

it seems that my user on Android lost the "owner privileges": Any function or feature that is only available to the main user is disabled in the UI. Unfortunately, this includes user administration and all backup functionality. It seems that I became a secondary user, but I do have the data of the original main user.

Is there any way to get owner privileges back?

This happened after flashing different kernels of Android 10. I do have the correct stock kernel now.

Best Regards!